# Russian film vaguely similar to Legion (2010)

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying really hard to identify this movie I watched a long time ago. I guess it was made around the mid-2000s. It's a Russian film in which an angel is sent to Earth to do battle against the forces of darkness or something like that.

I vaguely remember a scene in which he meets another angel in a motorhome and this angel has been a long time on Earth and he points the main character (which I believe is the Archangel Gabriel) to the right direction. It's set in Moscow and it has this dark and gritty, almost post-apocalyptic feeling.

After looking around I could say this film is similar in style to *Night Watch* and *Day Watch*, but that's as far as I've gotten.

Comment: In roughly which year did you actually watch this?

Comment: I'm unsure, but I'd say somewhere between 2005-2010.

Answer (score 0):

**POSSIBLY *NIGHT WATCH* OR ITS SEQUEL *DAY WATCH***

*N[ight Watch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Watch_(2004_film))* is a 2004 Russian urban fantasy supernatural thriller film, loosely based on the 1998 novel *The Night Watch* by Sergei Lukyanenko. *[Day Watch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_Watch_(film))* is a 2006 sequel.

[image]

It has the battle between good and evil (quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Watch_(2004_film))):

> Since the beginning of time, there have been "Others" – humans endowed with supernatural abilities – and for just as long, the Others have been divided between the forces of Light and Dark. In Medieval times, the armies of both sides met by chance, and a great battle began. Seeing that neither side had a clear advantage, the two faction leaders, Geser and Zavulon, called a truce and each side commissioned a quasi-police force to ensure it was kept; the Light side's force was called the Night Watch and the Dark side's force was called the Day Watch. (...) Anton has enlisted in the Night Watch. While policing Moscow, he encounters several portents that Geser says are linked to an ancient prophecy of an immensely powerful Other that will end the stalemate between Light and Dark, but will be more likely to join the Dark.

I remember it as being rather grim, nearly post-apocalyptic. I don't remember enough to say if it has the trailer park scene you mention.

Comment: The author mentions it's "similar to Night Watch and Day Watch", so I'm guessing those two movies are excluded ;)